# A verb for a 'swarm' of men?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

For example a whole crowd of men surrounded and beat someone up.

Comment: Squad, gang, clan - take your pick.

Comment: Maybe a **mob**.

Comment: Bunch... BTW, what is your question?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for a verb and not a noun?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say *mob* is your best bet.

> A mob surrounded him and beat him up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the word; horde.

> A horde is a disparaging word for ‘a large group of people’, as in hordes of fans descended on the stage. Instances of hoard being used instead of horde are not uncommon: around a quarter of citations for hoard in the Oxford English Corpus are for the incorrect use.

Oxford Dictionary of English